# TM1PY Adding new Edge

Tags: python-3.x

Using TM1PY, I am attempting to add new elements to an existing Dimension. Below please find the code employed. The element is added to the dimension, but the edge creation seems to be incorrect as the new element is not a child of the specified parent. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
for row in newVendors.head().iterrows():    
    element = Element(name=str(row[1]["element_id"]), element_type="Numeric")

    self.tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.elements.create(
        dimension_name=self.dimensionName,
        hierarchy_name=self.dimensionName,
        element=element)

    hierarchy = Hierarchy(name=self.dimensionName, dimension_name=self.dimensionName)          
    hierarchy.add_edge(str(int(row[1]["parent_id"])), str(int(row[1]["element_id"])), 1)
```

Joe

@Marias Thank you for the clarification. I have utilized the second approach, but am still getting errors. The dimension has several attributes and the add_edges throws an error: "Attribute not found." Here is my modified code snippet:
'''

```
self.tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.elements.create(self.dimensionName, 
                                            self.dimensionName, 
                                            Element("e4", "Numeric"))

self.tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.elements.create(self.dimensionName, 
                                            self.dimensionName,  
                                            Element("c1", "Consolidated"))
self.tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.add_edges("d1", "d1", edges={("c1", "e4"): 1})
```

''''

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to update a TM1 Hierarchy with TM1py.

**Option1**
You retrieve the existing hierarchy, manipulate it, and send it back.

```py
from TM1py import TM1Service

ADDRESS, PORT, SSL, USER, PASSWORD = "localhost", "12354", True, "admin", "apple"

with TM1Service(address=ADDRESS, port=PORT, ssl=SSL, user=USER, password=PASSWORD) as tm1:
    hierarchy = tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.get("d1", "d1")
    hierarchy.add_element("c1", "Consolidated")
    hierarchy.add_element("e4", "Numeric")
    hierarchy.add_edge(parent="c1", component="e4", weight=1)
    tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.update(hierarchy)
```

This makes sense if you are planning to do bigger changes to the hierarchy.
It will be faster in most cases.

**Option2**
You add elements and edges to the hierarchy through individual requests.

```py
from TM1py import TM1Service, Element

ADDRESS, PORT, SSL, USER, PASSWORD = "localhost", "12354", True, "admin", "apple"

with TM1Service(address=ADDRESS, port=PORT, ssl=SSL, user=USER, password=PASSWORD) as tm1:
    tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.elements.create("d1", "d1", Element("e4", "Numeric"))
    tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.elements.create("d1", "d1", Element("c1", "Consolidated"))
    tm1.dimensions.hierarchies.add_edges("d1", "d1", edges={("c1", "e4"): 1})
```

This makes sense if you are just adding one or two elements to a large dimension.

Currently, you are mixing the two approaches. You must choose one or the other.

Make sure you are using the latest version of TM1py (1.5.0). You can upgrade TM1py with pip: `pip install tm1py --upgrade`